# Cannot add images to new image column after databinding DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I cannot set the image of an image column cell after I databind the DataGridView.

If I add the image column and the image without databinding the dgv, everything works.

Here is my code:

```
public void LoadDgvDocuments()
{
    var select = "SELECT RegistryTypeId, RegistryTypeDescription FROM RegistryType";
    SqlConnection c = SqlDbConnection.GetConnection();
    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);
    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dgvDocuments.ReadOnly = true;
    dgvDocuments.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dgvDocuments.Columns[0].Width = 100;
    dgvDocuments.Columns[1].Width = 250;
    AddDeleteIconColumns();
    dgvDocuments.Columns[2].Width = 50;
}

public void AddDeleteIconColumns()
{
    DataGridViewImageColumn ic = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    ic.HeaderText = "Img";
    ic.Image = null;
    ic.Name = "cImg";
    ic.Width = 100;
    dgvDocuments.Columns.Add(ic);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDocuments.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[2] as DataGridViewImageCell;
        cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Icon_delete;
    }
}
```

When I use the code I get this:

[image: not working]

When I don't databind and just load the image column, everything works:

[image: working]

Could this be because of an issue in the dgv. Because the column numbering is messed up when I checked:

[image: messed up column numbering]

I just need to display the image in the image column.

Comment: Your code works just fine here. No funny numbering etc.. General advice: You should not rely on some magic numbers when accessing the column. Instead write : `int cix = dgvDocuments.Columns.Add(ic);` and then `DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[cix] as DataGridViewImageCell;` or, as the column has a name you know: `DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells["cImg"] as DataGridViewImageCell;`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with MDI form and Dgv shown here:

[view article describing issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b9c01020-c193-4401-a687-f49250a74021/mdiparent-property-and-datagridview-problem?forum=vbgeneral)

Used this code and it works:

```
  private void dgvDocuments_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {  
        if (dgvDocuments.ColumnCount < 5)
        {
            InsertDocumentColumn();
        }
    }
```